Getting Bond Dimension in qiskit Matrix Product State Simulation
I am setting up some circuit simulation in qiskit_aer using the MPS method. I am performing exact simulation (important for this task specifically). I am using the following setup:
simulator = AerSimulator(method='matrix_product_state',
    enable_truncation = False,
    zero_threshold = None,
    validation_threshold = None,
    matrix_product_state_max_bond_dimension = None,
    matrix_product_state_truncation_threshold = None,
    chop_threshold = None
    )

Is there a way to get the maximum-bond dimension during the simulation? This would be very important for my result documentation. Thank you in advance!
